# Typescript compile files from few source folders

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have 3 NodeJs apps with Typescript code (latest versions).
In each one of the apps there is an "src" folder which contains the ts code files and a "dist" folder that contains the js files compiled by Typescript.
Now I want to create outside of these apps folders a "common" folder that will contain few ts files that each one of my 3 apps can use and it should be compiled to the "dist" folder of each app separately.
Instead of using `"rootDir": "./src"` I tried using `"rootDirs":["../../common", "/.src"]`
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to create workspaces. The package manager you use should have support for workspaces built-in. Like [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) or [NPM workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces).